# animate google maps markers when the map scrolls into view

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

so I have google map on the bottom of a page with animated markers. Markers have drop animation but I want for animation to start when map scrolls into view - without that animation is over when user eventually scrolls down to see the map.
I'm using google maps api.

My code:

```
var marker;

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: {lat: 59.325, lng: 18.070}
  });

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: {lat: 59.327, lng: 18.067}
  });
  marker.addListener('click', toggleBounce);
}

function toggleBounce() {
  if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
    marker.setAnimation(null);
  } else {
    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery visible to check if the map element on your view is visible by the user. Then if the view is visible start the animation.

[jquery visible tutorial](https://www.customd.com/articles/13/checking-if-an-element-is-visible-on-screen-using-jquery)

[jquery visible github](https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible)

```
//set an interval that keeps checking if the user can see the map
//the interval will keep calling your initMap()
var myVar = setInterval(function () { initMap() }, 10);

function initMap() {
// check if the user can see the map using $('#map').visible()
    if ($('#map').visible()) {
        //if the user can see the map stop checking
        clearInterval(myVar);

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 13,
            center: { lat: 59.325, lng: 18.070 }
        });

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: { lat: 59.327, lng: 18.067 }
        });
        marker.addListener('click', toggleBounce);
    }
}



function toggleBounce() {
    if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
        marker.setAnimation(null);
    } else {
        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    }
}
```

If you want you can edit this code to load the map first and then add the marker once the user can see the map.

```
//set an interval that keeps checking if the user can see the map
//the interval will keep calling your initMap()
var myVar = setInterval(function () { addMarker() }, 100);

function initMap() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: { lat: 59.325, lng: 18.070 }
    });

    function addMarker() {
        // check if the user can see the map using $('#map').visible()
        if ($('#map').visible()) {
            //if the user can see the map stop checking
            clearInterval(myVar);

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                draggable: true,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                position: { lat: 59.327, lng: 18.067 }
            });
            marker.addListener('click', toggleBounce);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Quick note you can change the interval time if you want... I have it checking every 10 milliseconds.

Comment: hi, sorry that I didn't reply still, your answer seems good to me but I have some unexpected things to solve. I will be back as soon as possible to see if it works. Thank you for the lovely answer

Comment: Sounds good Goran. I hope this answer works well for you. In your research if you find other creative ways of solving this problem please share them so we can all learn. Thanks!